# unserialize(): Error at offset X of Y bytes

Tags: php, phpunit, joomla3.5

I am trying to create tests using PHPUnit in Joomla. After having several errors This is what I have:

**pathToProject/tests/pruebastests.php:**

```
<?php   
class PruebasTest extends  PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSimple0()
    {
        $a = 3-1;
        $this->assertEquals(2, $a);     
    }

    public function testSimple1()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(2, 1 + 2);        
    }

    public function testSimple2()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(2, 1+1);        
    }
}
```

when I run in that path:

```
 phpunit pruebatests.php
```

it gives me an error:

> EF.
>
> Time: 3.18 seconds, Memory: 5.75MB
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) PruebasTest::testSimple0 unserialize(): Error at offset 3919 of
>   8500 bytes

It is always on the first test it runs. I mean, If I delete testSimple0 function I receive the same error with testSimple1

I have read other StackOverflow Questions related with this unserialize error but they did not help me.

EDIT: If I try it in a different PC with a different file in the same project the error is:

> unserialize(): Error at offset 4189 of 8484 bytes

I have realized that the error is related to bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('BASEPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('JOOMLA_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
define('JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
if (file_exists(JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH . '/defines.php'))
{
    include_once JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH);
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
define('JPATH_COMPONENT', JOOMLA_ADMIN_PATH . '/components/com_content');
$app = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
```

If I comment the last line the error disappears. But if I do that I cannot instance any controller...

Any idea? I am using Joomla 3.5 and PHPUnit 4.8

Comment: I can't reproduce this. There's something else going on that isn't shown here. When I run this test, I get `.F.  1) PruebasTest::testSimple1
Failed asserting that 3 matches expected 2.`

Comment: Try upgrading to phpunit > 5 https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1571

Comment: The result is the same with 5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache. I have met such a problem. In symfony the reason was old *.meta files in /var/cache

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't remember what I did. This was 6 years ago. But re reading the question I tried in 2 different PCs so I don' think cache was the problem.